# How to decode Google Tag Manager JSON

Tags: php, json, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager library for getting all tags on my account. I'm getting JSON data from `https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/tagmanager/v2/rest`. This JSON is not working for me and I cannot decode it with PHP.

Example:

```
{ 
   "tag":[ 
      { 
         "path":"tags/1",
         "accountId":"1"
      },
      { 
         "path":"tags/2",
         "accountId":"1"
      }
   ],
   "tag":[ 
      { 
         "path":"tags/1",
         "accountId":"2"
      },
      { 
         "path":"tags/2",
         "accountId":"2"
      }
   ],
   "tag":[ 
      { 
         "path":"tags/1",
         "accountId":"3"
      }
   ]
}
```

And testing it on [json debugger website](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) I have error `Duplicate key, names should be unique.`.

How I can fix this JSON to make it working with PHP `json_decode($json, true)`?

Previous ugly code

```
$json = str_replace('\n', '', $get_json);
$json = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $json);
$json = str_replace('}{}{', ',', $json);
$json = str_replace('}{', ',', $json);
$json = str_replace('&quot;tag&quot;: [', '&quot;tag&quot;: ', $json);
$json = str_replace('} } ]', '} } }', $json);
$json = str_replace('tag&quot;:', 'tag_manage&quot;:', $json);
$json = str_replace('tag_manage', 'tag_manage', $json);
$json = preg_replace('/tag_manage/', 'tag_1_manage', $json, 1);
$json = preg_replace('/tag_manage/', 'tag_2_manage', $json, 1);
$json = preg_replace('/tag_manage/', 'tag_3_manage', $json, 1);
```

Comment: This does not look like a response from the GTM API. What request are you sending to the API to get this kind of response? Expected reponse is a single key of "tag" and then an array of objects with the actual tags: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/workspaces/tags/list?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22accounts%2F325739068%2Fcontainers%2F12898106%2Fworkspaces%2F59%22%7D

Answer (score 0):

You have several attributes of the same object called `tag`. Something like

```
{ 
   {"tag":[ 
      { 
         "path":"tags/1",
         "accountId":"1"
      },
      { 
         "path":"tags/2",
         "accountId":"1"
      }
   ]},
   {"tag":[ 
      { 
         "path":"tags/1",
         "accountId":"2"
      },
      { 
         "path":"tags/2",
         "accountId":"2"
      }
   ]},
   {"tag":[ 
      { 
         "path":"tags/1",
         "accountId":"3"
      }
   ]}
}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found the JSON is incorrect - it would be like having an object in PHP with several variables all called `tag`.  Your JSON should probably have all the data under the one `tag` element, something like...

```
{ 
   "tag":[ 
      { 
         "path":"tags/1",
         "accountId":"1"
      },
      { 
         "path":"tags/2",
         "accountId":"1"
      },
      { 
         "path":"tags/1",
         "accountId":"2"
      },
      { 
         "path":"tags/2",
         "accountId":"2"
      },
      { 
         "path":"tags/1",
         "accountId":"3"
      }
   ]
}
```

The code to alter it update this (once the existing data is correct) would be something like....

```
// Fetch existing data
$json = file_get_contents("a.json");
// Decode data to array format
$tags = json_decode($json, true );
// Add new tag into the data
$tags['tag'][] = ["path" => "tags/1", "accountId" => "4"];
// Create new JSON encoded string
$newJson = json_encode($tags, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```